# how large can the periodic table become?

Tags: atomic-physics, atoms, elements

Until recently, four new chemicals were added to the periodic table, thus completing the seventh row of the same. It is four superheavy chemical elements (113, 115, 117 and 118) have been discovered by scientists from Japan, Russia and the United States.

They are the first to be added to the table since the 114 elements were added in 2011 and 116. The four were verified on 30 December by the International Union of Pure and Applied Chemistry (IUPAC)

IUPAC has initiated the process of formalizing the names and symbols for these elements, which have been temporarily named as' ununtrium '(' Uut 'or element 113),' ununpentium '(' Uup ', element 115),' ununseptium '(' Uus', element 117), and 'ununoctium' ('Uuo', element 118) "

then, few more elements may contain the periodic table?

Comment: obviously behind this question lies the fact of knowing what makes a stable atom? or, how prontones or neutrons can be added?

Comment: Or is there is an island of stability?

Comment: It is not clear how many elements  beyond the expected island of stability are physically possible. Those heavy cores are highly unstable and hard to produce and even harder to measure. On https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_periodic_table#End_of_the_periodic_table there are some points on possible limits. The latest absolute maximum limit seems to be $Z\sim173$.

Comment: why the latest absolute maximum limit seems to be Z∼173?

Comment: Sorry but have you read the wikipedia article? I got that number from there and there it is explained where it comes from alongside with the other stuff concerning that high Z region of the periodic table.